# Can motherboard rust?

Tags: motherboard

I spilled shampoo on my laptop recently. gave it to the tech guys, they cleaned it and it was working fine. After a month suddenly the control alt and shift buttons were not working when pressed together. Now the shift key is not working. The tech guys say the mother board has rusted after the shampoo spill and it needs replacement. The laptop is working absolutely fine except the shift key. I think the tech guy is cheating me.Please help.

Comment: What is causing your problems is the keyboard PCB not your motherboard, but the solution is the same, replace the broken compondent.  It sounds like you believe you can live with your laptop being broken.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking if motherboards can rust (corrode) or are you asking us to tell you if you are being cheated? Please [edit] your question to be specific. Did the tech provide any pictures of the rust?

Comment: you can generally replace a laptop keyboard with a bit of effort. I'd try to find a new one and give it a try. it is certainly a cheaper thing to start with than a motherboard replacement.

Comment: If you plug an USB keyboard and everything works fine, then the problem is the keyboard (which is probably the case).

Answer (score 1):

Rust is a specific type of corrosion related to iron. Sometimes people use the word "rust" to describe all types of corrosion. There may even be small amounts of iron in the components of the motherboard.

As far as a motherboard, corrosion can develop if exposed to moisture. According to the site madehow.com;

> The primary ingredient in all shampoos is water, typically making up
>   about 70-80% of the entire formula.
>   (http://www.madehow.com/Volume-3/Shampoo.html)

Therefore, your motherboard was exposed to moisture and could very possibly have some corrosion. Exposure to moisture is never a good thing for electronics.

Is it the cause of the keyboard malfunction? We cannot answer that with certainty without seeing the corrosion and knowing what circuits are affected.

Other Reference: [What is corrosion?](https://www.electrochem.org/dl/interface/spr/spr06/spr06_p24-26.pdf)

Comment: +1  However, the simpler answer, is yes.  Components on the motherboard can rust.